# Trabalhando com alta carga de processamento em uma tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, banco-de-dados

Quais são as possíveis estratégias de modelagem de banco de dados em um cenário onde se tem uma tabela específica que recebe uma carga gigantesca de `statements` de `insert`, `update` e `delete`, além de consultas com alto processamento de dados, requisitando milhares de registros por vez?

Tendo em vista que a tabela tende a ficar cada vez maior e que as requisições simultâneas e de larga escala podem tornar o banco temporariamente inacessível (causando constantes `timeouts`), existe alguma forma de lidar com este tipo de cenário? Seja na aplicação ou modificando a estrutura da tabela ou da modelagem ER.

Comment: 1 - Não utilizar nenhum BD relacional e sim NoSQL. (Levando em conta `carga gigantesca, alto processamento, milhares de registros`)

Comment: @rubStackOverflow, a pergunta é relacionada a possíveis estratégias utilizando um modelo ER com SQL Server. Infelizmente não é uma opção hoje modificar a tecnologia do banco para NoSQL por questões de força maior.. =/

Comment: Entendido @vinícius

Comment: Os timeouts você não consegue resolver fazendo um tunning na memória do sql server? Tive um problema de timeouts constantes e, na época, foi o que resolveu. Deixei 2 GB para o sistema operacional e o resto para o banco. [exemplo](https://avmsistemasinfo.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/sqlserver_memory.png)

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia Vinicius,
não sou nenhum expert em banco de dados, mas vou tentar ajudar indicando ações que acredito que irão te ajudar.

**1) Considere particionar sua tabela.**

Se sua tabela possui um volume muito grande de registros, na casa dos milhões, considere particioná-la. Dessa forma você não precisará varrer toda a tua tabela sempre que fizer um SELECT. Você varrerá apenas a partição em que se encontra o registro. Você não disse qual a versão do seu SQL Server, mas segue um link que pode te ajudar -> http://www.devmedia.com.br/particionamento-de-tabelas-no-sql-server-2008-r2/24237

**2) Considere duplicar algumas informações para diminuir a concorrência.**

Por exemplo, se você possui a mesma informação em mais de uma tabela, você não precisará ir sempre na mesma tabela para obter tal informação, você poderá buscar a mesma informação nas outras tabelas dependendo da sua necessidade. Isso também diminuirá sua quantidade de INNER JOINS. Mas lembrando que ao duplicar informações, é preciso ter cuidado ao alterar e excluir esses registros, na maioria das vezes você terá que excluir de todas as tabelas em que você duplicou tal informação.
um pouco mais sobre concorrência -> http://www.devmedia.com.br/controle-de-concorrencia-entre-transacoes-em-bancos-de-dados/27756

**3) Considere o agendamento de processos.**

O SQL Server permite que sejam agendados alguns processos (JOB).
Analise se existe alguma rotina que pode ser agendada para ser executada em horário alternativos, de madrugada por exemplo.
https://fabrizziocaputo.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/sql-server-basico-4-agendando-um-job-no-sql-server/

**4) Considere a criação de filas.**

Você criar na sua aplicação um esquema de filas de processamento.
Por exemplo: Se existe um relatório muito pesado para ser gerado, e várias pessoas estão solicitando o mesmo relatório, faça com que essas solicitações caiam em uma fila, e sejam processadas uma a uma. Dessa forma você não onera o banco apenas com processamento desse relatório.

**5) Considere a criação de índices.**

um pouco mais sobre índices no sql server -> http://www.devmedia.com.br/indices-no-sql-server/18353

Como eu disse, não sou nenhum expert em banco, mas talvez essas dicas lhe sirvam

Espero ter ajudado!